# Inkscape can not blur Bezier line if it is connected to the outer end of a spiral

Tags: inkscape, blur

I have added a `Bezier line` to the outer end of a `spiral`. (See comment for details.)
After that I selected both, colorized them and gave them a small amount of blur (1.5%).

The problem is, that **only** the `spiral` gets blury, but not the `Bezier line`.
[image: Only spiral gets blured]

Nevertheless, if I move one `node` of the `Bezier line` somewhere else to the outer `path` of the `spiral`, select them both and apply a blur, **both** get blured. I moved the node with the `Edit paths by nodes` tool and enabled `Enable snapping` -> `Snap notes or handles` -> `Snap to paths`.
[image: Spiral and line get blured]

Next I can drag one `node of the blured Bezier line` to the `cusp node of the blured spiral` by hand and level the `line` horizontal, by entering the same y-value for the `right node` that the `left node` has. Now I can select them both and can change the blur of them **simulataneously**. By that I can achieve the result that I could not get by the first method. (See **EDIT**)
[image: Workaround by moving the line to the spiral after bluring it]

*I would like to know, how I can blur both objects at the same time without all the effort described above, if this is not a bug.*

```
user@hostname:~$ apt-cache show inkscape 
Package: inkscape
[…]
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.48.3.1-1ubuntu6.1
[…]
```

**[EDIT]:**
After messing arround with the problem for another while I realised, that the `blur of the line` only disapears, if I level the `two nodes of the line` exactly one the same `y-values` with **copy and paste**.
In my first try I entered the `y-value of the left node of the line` in the "y-value box" (at top) of the `right line-node` **by hand**, what probably results in not exact the same numbers as copy and paste does.
In my second try to recreate the problem, I **copied and pasted** the `y-value from the left line-node to the right line-node` and as soon as I did that the `blur of the line` disapears.

*I could not find any information that this behaviour is intended by the developers. Thus I guess this is a bug and I will report it to them and write about the progress in here.*

Comment: How did you "add" or "connect" the line to the spiral? Did you group the objects? Did you join them with nodes?

Comment: @boo2060 I have drawn the `spiral` with exactly three turns, selected the `Bezier curve and straight lines` tool and set its mode to `paraxial line mode`. After that I enabled `Enable snapping` -> `Snap nodes or handles` -> `snap to cusp node` (on the right hand side of the window). Now when I hover the cursor over the outer end point of the spiral, the **cursor snaps to it** and it can draw a `straight line` to the right with **no interception** to the `spiral`. Can I call that a connection or is that reserved for sth. else? Sorry, that I have not described that better in the first place.

Comment: This _has_ to be a bug. Please report it to the Inkscape developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following answer from the Inkscape developer *~suv*:

> Technically not a bug - a horizontal (or vertical) line has only one
>   dimension, and the filter effects region thus too (i.e. the blur is
>   not visible).
>
> **Workarounds:**
>   - Combine the line with the spiral (the bounding box of the resulting paths as two dimensions), and blur the combined path.
>   - Group the line with the spiral, and blur the group, instead of the individual objects.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1187728